# Ideals and Idempotents in a commutative ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, ideals

Let $I$, $J$, and $K$ be pairwise comaximal ideals of a commutative ring $R$ with $1$  with the property that  if $x^2-x\in I$, then there exists $e^2=e\in J$ such that $x-e\in I$ and if $y^2-y\in K$, then there exists $f^2=f\in J$ such that $y-f\in K$, where $x, y\in R$. I am looking for conditions on $I$, $J$, and $K$ under which we can find an idempotent element $h^2=h\in R$ such that $h\in I$ and $1-h\in K$.( Perhaps such an $h$ This can be found without any assumption)

Comment: Note: $I,J$ comaximal means $I+J=R$.

Comment: What's your favorite example of such a ring and such a trio of ideals?